# Render EJS Asynchronously (Render first then data)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm quite new to using engine templates, and need a bit of help.

I'm using the EJS template engine to render my HTML and was wondering if it could essentially render the HTML page first and then my data.

For example:

I have a page render as the following that calls a function in its data object:

```
res.render(root + "/pages/home/home.ejs", {
     data: render()
});
```

This render() function is quite heavy and takes a couple of seconds to complete. I was wondering if I can serve the HTML file first and then allow for the data to come through to the page asynchronously when it completes?

I'd also would like to avoid doing:

```
render().then(data => {
    res.render(root + "/pages/home/home.ejs", {
        data: data
    })
})
```

Any suggestion or other template engines should I use would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering your application on server side (`res.render()`). So you cannot bind data after rendering the template. This is because when you are using server side rendering you are generating a html on the server and send it as the response. Afterward you don't have access to the client side code. (like php)

In this case you have to user a client end http request to get data. Then fill them in on the client side. You have to create a http api in the server side.

Comment: Thanks for that, ah in this case, i'll probably go the socket version rather then exposing an API route (?) i.e. serve the static file and then use socket io to update the page when data is ready